# Getting a high level overview of comparative size differences of binary files?

Tags: binary-analysis, radare2, bin-diffing

I have two binary files, one of them is pulled from [Protostar's (`stack0` example)](https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/exploit-exercises-protostar-v2,32/). The other one I compiled ([from source](http://liveoverflow.com/binary_hacking/protostar/stack0.html)) with the latest version of GCC. The size difference is massive. My version is 11.5 Kb. The Protostar distributed version is 21.9 Kb. How would I get a high level overview to work towards an understanding of the massive difference in sizes?

I am compiling my version with

```
CFLAGS=-m32 -fno-stack-protector -std=c89 -fno-PIE -no-pie -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -fno-chkp-use-wrappers -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -fno-check-pointer-bounds -z execstack -z norelro -Os
```

- When I use Radare's show info with `i` **everything** is the same, except for the sizes.
- The main functions are both very similar.

I'm just wondering what caused the original to be so much bigger. Is there an option or tool for something like `radiff2` that can help me drill down to explain what my compiler is now doing differently than the compiler it was compiled with?

Comment: What is protostar and how are the two files related?

Comment: They're both supposed to be compiled from the same source, but potentially a different set of compiler options or different compiler altogether (I just wanted to generate a similar `main` so I played with `gcc` until I got something good. But, I want to understand what else changed.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky see my answer, be curious to know what you think of that and if that's a good place to start to figure out this?

Comment: "except for the sizes."... so which sizes are different and how?

Comment: What does `file` give you on the two binaries? Perhaps one is stripped and the other isn't? Also one could be statically linked and perhaps not against glibc at all (for example musl-libc comes to mind as libc which is standards-compliant and yields small binaries)

Answer (score 2):

[Bloaty McBloatFace](https://github.com/google/bloaty) is a compiled binary size profiler that can provide a breakdown of section sizes as you have there as well as a number of other ways to break things out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to accept this answer, because likely someone else will tell me a better way to do it. But, browsing the site I saw an old picture of Radare that seemed to kind of do what I want with an `S=` option. This is showing the breakdown by section. That seemed like a good place to start.

[image]

Turns out that's now really close to the [undocumented `iS=` option](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/12111).

Using that on both binaries, I saw the difference **really** quick,

```
[0x00000000]> iS=
00  0x00000000 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x00000000     0 ---      
01  0x08048114 |-#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048127    19 r--  .interp
02  0x08048128 |-#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048148    32 r--  .note.ABI_tag
03  0x08048148 |-#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804816c    36 r--  .note.gnu.build_id
04  0x0804816c |-#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048198    44 r--  .hash
05  0x08048198 |-#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x080481b8    32 r--  .gnu.hash
06  0x080481b8 |-##-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048218    96 r--  .dynsym
07  0x08048218 |--#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048267    79 r--  .dynstr
08  0x08048268 |--#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048274    12 r--  .gnu.version
09  0x08048274 |--#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048294    32 r--  .gnu.version_r
10  0x08048294 |--#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804829c     8 r--  .rel.dyn
11  0x0804829c |--##----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x080482bc    32 r--  .rel.plt
12  0x080482bc |---#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x080482ec    48 r-x  .init
13  0x080482ec |---#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804833c    80 r-x  .plt
14  0x08048340 |---###--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x080484dc   412 r-x  .text
15  0x080484dc |-----#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x080484f8    28 r-x  .fini
16  0x080484f8 |-----#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048534    60 r--  .rodata
17  0x08048534 |-----#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048538     4 r--  .eh_frame
18  0x08049538 |-----#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08049540     8 rw-  .ctors
19  0x08049540 |-----#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08049548     8 rw-  .dtors
20  0x08049548 |-----#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804954c     4 rw-  .jcr
21  0x0804954c |-----##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804961c   208 rw-  .dynamic
22  0x0804961c |------#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08049620     4 rw-  .got
23  0x08049620 |------#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804963c    28 rw-  .got.plt
24  0x0804963c |-------#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08049644     8 rw-  .data
25  0x08049644 |-------#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804964c     0 rw-  .bss
26* 0x00000000 |-------############-------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x00000a68  2.6K ---  .stab
27* 0x00000000 |------------------###################################################################-------------| 0x00003a5c 14.6K ---  .stabstr
28* 0x00000000 |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#-------------| 0x00000039    57 ---  .comment
29* 0x00000000 |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------##------------| 0x000000fd   253 ---  .shstrtab
30* 0x00000000 |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#####--| 0x00000440    1K ---  .symtab
31* 0x00000000 |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------##| 0x0000020c   524 ---  .strtab
32  0x08048034 |##------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048114   224 r-x  PHDR
33  0x08048114 |-#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048127    19 r--  INTERP
34  0x08048000 |######--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048538  1.3K r-x  LOAD0
35  0x08049538 |-----###------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804964c   268 rw-  LOAD1
36  0x0804954c |-----##-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804961c   208 rw-  DYNAMIC
37  0x08048128 |-#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x0804816c    68 r--  NOTE
38  0x00000000 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x00000000     0 rwx  GNU_STACK
39  0x08048000 |#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 0x08048034    52 rw-  ehdr
=>  0x00000000 |^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^| 0xffffffffffffffff
```

That `.stabstr` thing was **huge.** [I found this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8657396/124486),

> I'd be surprised if the debugging format was stabs on either platform unless you had explicitly requested it with `-gstabs` as an argument to gcc.

I enabled that option and suddenly my new binary had one too, and it was pretty close in size to the old one.